# How to write a vlookup in vba in a sheet that contains 5000 rows of data?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim z As Long
    z = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C4").Formula ="=Vlookup(A4, '[EMP.txt]EMP'!$A$2:$C2,3,False)"
    Range("C4").Copy
    Range("C4:C" & z).pastspecial xlPasteAll
End sub
```

My formula works in my code but it omits a couple rows so my totals don’t match. If I change the vlookup Formula to `=Vlookup(A4,’[EMP.txt]EMP’!$A$2:$C176,3,False)`, it will pull over everything but the range will change on a week to week basis. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you are asking. How do you fix what? The range where you want to search? something like `Vlookup(A4,’[EMP.txt]EMP’!$A$2:$C" & z & ",3,False` should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Becasue in your code you already have a variable named `z` where you store row of last non-blank cell in Column A, you can use that same row number to update your range in your `Vlookup`

So replace line:

```
Range("C4").Formula ="=Vlookup(A4, '[EMP.txt]EMP'!$A$2:$C2,3,False)"
```

With

```
Range("C4").Formula ="=Vlookup(A4, '[EMP.txt]EMP'!$A$2:$C" & z & ",3,False)"
```